# Keycloak client id strategy for a micro service plattform

Tags: microservices, keycloak, keycloak-services

Hello fellow programmers.

I hope there are some keycloak experts out there that can help me to solve my question.

So my situation is that we have microservice platform with ~20 services which in the future should be secured using keycloak jwt tokens.

The idea is that we offer an interface for our clients where they can register themselves with a password/key pair within one realm and they should be able to use that account to access all the 
services through a public facade/api.

Now to the question - how to handle the client id - in all examples each service has its own specific client id - should this in our case be the client id of the public api//facade which allows the inner services or is there better approach how to handle this without forcing the user to log in for each service...

Thanks in advance for all help and I hope you are all doing well...

Gerrit

P.s. Maybe to clarify my question further - my current understanding is that for each. service i should add a new client to my realm but my users then would need to get a token for each service/client as each client owns his own secret... and I want my users to be able to use one token for all our services.

Answer (score 1):

So after wrapping my head around this issue and reading the docs:

> clients
>   Clients are entities that can request Keycloak to authenticate a user. Most often, clients are applications and services that want to use Keycloak to secure themselves and provide a single sign-on solution. Clients can also be entities that just want to request identity information or an access token so that they can securely invoke other services on the network that are secured by Keycloak.

I think to use one client for my user accounts for the whole platform is the proper way to go.

Would be perfect if one of the keycloak experts can acknowledge this.